# Google storage usage on two accounts are counted different

Tags: google-drive, google-plus

I have two google accounts and about 1GB uploaded photos on each. I see that on my first account photos use storage, but on another no (0% used of 15GB). All photos are max 1600 pixels width/height. What is going on ?

First Google account

[image: First Google account]

Second Google account

[image: Second Google account]

**UPDATE**

I saw that on first account i don't have a something like "Profile"(accessible on url `https://profiles.google.com`), I see only `Join Google+` button. However on the second account i have a profile, but I have to notice that **on both account Google+ is deactivated** - when i go to `https://plus.google.com` i see page `Join Google+ by creating your public profile`. Strange, what is this profile on the second account where GPlus is off ?

First Google account

[image]

Second Google account

[image]

Comment: Have the photo's been uploaded to the empty account or have they been shared by another Google account?

Comment: What do You mean "shared by another account" ? How to check this ? The second account (with 0% usage) is newer.

Comment: When you look at the photos on Drive, do you see the word "shared" next to them?

Comment: I don't see photos on Google Drive at all. I see photos only on `https://picasaweb.google.com/`. Only one photo is public, all other are private.

Answer (score 1):

[This Google Support article](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en) should help answer your question. If you upload photos through Auto backup as full size images (the default), they count towards your usage. It also appears that when you are manually uploading the same logic is used.

Comment: Yes, all photos are max 1600 (default in Picasa)